init_fs_encoding during deploying django app to apache
i'm trying for hours to deploy a django app on an apache2 and still get following error:
  PYTHONHOME = '/home/rickmanns/bar/bar/djenv'
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'python3'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  safe_path = 0
  import site = 1
  is in build tree = 0
  stdlib dir = '/home/rickmanns/bar/bar/djenv/lib/python3.11'
  sys._base_executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.base_prefix = '/home/rickmanns/bar/bar/djenv'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/home/rickmanns/bar/bar/djenv'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.prefix = '/home/rickmanns/bar/bar/djenv'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/home/rickmanns/bar/bar/djenv'
  sys.path = [
    '/home/rickmanns/bar/bar/djenv/lib/python311.zip',
    '/home/rickmanns/bar/bar/djenv/lib/python3.11',
    '/home/rickmanns/bar/bar/djenv/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

My Apache config looks like following:
    Alias /static /home/rickmanns/bar/static
    <Directory /home/user/myproject/static>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/rickmanns/bar/bar>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess bar python-path=/home/rickmanns/bar python-home=/home/rickmanns/bar/djenv
    WSGIProcessGroup bar
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/rickmanns/bar/bar/wsgi.py

If it's helpful - i followed this tutorial: https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-django/
Thanks to everyone!

Your venv seems to be in /home/rickmanns/bar/bar/djenv/, but you declare the python-home as /home/rickmanns/bar/djenv.
Generally, that error points to an issue with the python home: https://discuss.python.org/t/fatal-python-error-init-fs-encoding-failed-to-get-the-python-codec-of-the-filesystem-encoding/3173/2
Try:
WSGIDaemonProcess bar python-path=/home/rickmanns/bar python-home=/home/rickmanns/bar/bar/djenv

Might have to check the python-path as well, depending on your project structure.
